# .NET Core Web API Handling Exceptions after a Response is already sent

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that exposes access to some long-running operations. Say for example a client is requesting the API to perform some calculation that takes a while. API delegates that request to a Service that is injected with a Repo and a Driver. The service will call the driver and pass in an anonymous function for the driver to communicate back progress, so that the service can update the repo accordingly. Put very simply, like this:

```
//throw new Exception("This exception won't cause a crash");
_driver.startCalculation(arg1, arg2, (status) => {
    //throw new Exception("This exception will cause a crash");
    _repo.updateStatus(status);
});
```

By the time the code in the anonymous function is executed, a response has already been sent to the client.

If an exception occurs outside of there, the client gets a 500 response and server survives. Inside of there, however, an exception will crash the whole API process.

I'm looking for any insight that will help me figure out how I *should* deal with this. Why does an exception in there cause a full-blown crash? My first idea is to just eat any exceptions in the anonymous function, but I'm concerned I might just be covering up a symptom of a design flaw.

Comment: Have you considere the obvious? A try/catch in the executing code block.

Comment: @TomTom that's what the last sentence is referring to. I know that's what I COULD do, but I'm wondering if that's what I SHOULD do or if I'm missing out on some language/framework feature or best practice I'm unaware of

Comment: When you say WebAPI. that means HTTP. and by HTTP it means one request and one response. If you are initialization a long running operation on background thread if will be eligible to be collected by GC just after you send response from the API.  If you are looking for some real-time feedback of and async operation. You need websockets. or you can use SignalR. Or you can use a [BackgroundHostedService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and use api calls to just track progress of BackgroundHostedService

Comment: "If you are initialization a long running operation on background thread if will be eligible to be collected by GC" - no, that is absolutely not how i.e. threads or tasks work, you know. The GC will honor those because the schedule start actually sets up a reference.

Comment: Where's `async/await`? Guessing that `async void` somewhere or you don't `catch` an exception at `await` or not `await` the method. Need more code to tell something useful. Is `startCalculation` `async`?

Comment: @aepot There is no async/await. The driver creates a new Process from an exe and attaches an Exit handler which will call the arg3 function with an appropriate status based on the exit code of the process

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to change your architecture to.

```
Request -> Server

(Server accepts the request with basic validation, but does not completely complete the workload).

Response <-  202 Response (NOT 200).
```

and then you come back later and poll for the completed work.

This is described more fully in the article below.

> //startQuote// One solution to this problem is to use HTTP polling.
> Polling is useful to client-side code, as it can be hard to provide
> call-back endpoints or use long running connections. Even when
> callbacks are possible, the extra libraries and services that are
> required can sometimes add too much extra complexity. //endQuote//

(from)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply

Comment: That's basically already what I'm doing. The anonymous function which updates the repo status is executed after the client has already received a response. The client can poll another endpoint to get the status that this anonymous function will eventually set.

Comment: The question is more about error handling under-the-hood. If any code is executing between the request and the response and it throws an exception that doesn't get explicitly handled, it seems like the framework will handle it. The client will get a 500, the API as a whole won't crash, and the singletons in my DI container will survive.

However if an exception is thrown and not handled in that anonymous function, which is executed after a response is sent, the entire API application will crash. I'm looking to better understand why